# how to link email with "&" in the email address

Tags: html, email, mailto

I just wanted to link an email in html with an email address in which "&" is there.. can it be possible with mailto method..?

```
<a href="mailto:bread&amp;butter@xyz.com" style="color:#5a5a5a; text-decoration:none;">Bread&amp;butter@xyz.com</a>
```

Comment: when I'm clicking on the above link it is only giving bread in email address bar..?

Comment: Is that even a valid email address?

Comment: yes.. it is a valid email address...

Comment: Seems like your browser's RFC5322 support is lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this..

```
<a href="mailto:bread%26butter@xyz.com" style="color:#5a5a5a; text-decoration:none;">Bread&amp;butter@xyz.com</a>
```

[Source](http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/94924-mailto-special-character-problem)